# How to automate the code to fetch data based on 2 filter conditions in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to fetch count of a output based on 2 filter condition between 2 columns. for example i am having 3 columns having 6 names, 6 subjects, marks. I want to fetch data of 1st name then each subject and its marks then 2nd name each subject and its marks, then 3rd name each subject and its marks and so on.

```
names = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
subjects = ['ABC','XYZ','PQR','EFG','GHT','XUV']

for i,j in [(names,subjects)]:
    a=df_master.loc[(df_master['names']==i) & 
                (df_master['subjects']==j),['Marks']]
    print(a)
```

I tried to fetch data using loc function but it wont help. I am expecting to get name of each students with each subjects and its marks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `zip` by both list and select all necessary columns in list:

```
for i,j in zip(names,subjects):
    a=df_master.loc[(df_master['names']==i) & 
                (df_master['subjects']==j),['names','subjects','Marks']]
    print(a)
```

If need all possible combinations loop in `groupby` object:

```
 for (i,j), g in df_master.groupby(['names','subjects']):
      a = g[['names','subjects','Marks']]
      print(a)
```

Comment: thanks. but hot to get a count of all the possible combinations name wise, can you help with that?

Comment: @Chinmay - Do you need `df = df_master.groupby(['names','subjects']).size().reset_index(name='count')` ?

Comment: main groupby code shows me all possible combinations thats fine but i want to get count of each combination, if one possible combination has 10 records i want to fetch its count

Comment: @Chinmay - Do you think first paragraph solution? like `count = ((df_master['names']==i) & 
                (df_master['subjects']==j)).sum()` ?

Comment: it worked thanks. one more question, i want to take a count of a student names category wise. I tried to run it through a loop but it shows only last category count.  category = ['A','B','C','D']
for i in category:
    j=df_master.loc[(df_master['Category'] == i), 
    ['Student_Name']]
    j.dropna()
    k=j.count()
    k=k.tolist()
    #break
print(k)